# how to hide icons from the Desktop in Kali Linux (all folders in the root appears in the desktop)

Tags: linux, icons, kali-linux

**I have asked this question before but from unregistered account which made me unable to answer any quires that had been raised**

I run many commands and I guess one of them made the following icons appear on the desktop :

```
Documents/Downloads/Music/Pictures/Public/Templates/Videos
```

Here is a screenshot of the icons:

[image]

I tried the dconf Editor as explained [here](http://lewiscomputerhowto.blogspot.co.uk/2013/10/how-to-add-or-remove-system-icons-from_9.html)

If I tried to delete them I can't access them when I open them from 'Computer' Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

The result of *ls -l /home/username/Desktop* is: ls: cannot access '-': No such file or directory

Comment: Exact duplicate of [how to hide icons from the Desktop in Kali Linux](http://superuser.com/q/1082723)

Comment: You appear to have created 2 accounts. See [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts) and/or [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) for guidance on how to merge your accounts.

Comment: you have to write the command as `ls -l /home/<username>/Desktop/`where you have to replace *<username>* with your username. Dont put spaces between `-` and `l`.

Comment: @jayde Then issue the command `ls -l /root/Desktop`

Comment: it didn't give any error and there is no output !

Comment: the Desktop folder which is in the root folder is empty

Comment: and all the files/folders on the actual desktop are in the root folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for a file called `/root/.config/user-dirs.dirs`. Check in the content of that file a line saying`XDG_DESKTOP_DIR=`.

It should be `XDG_DESKTOP_DIR=/root/Desktop`.

If it appears as `XDG_DESKTOP_DIR=/root` then there it's your problem. It believes that the Desktop is the root directory.

In that case, edit, change it to `XDG_DESKTOP_DIR=/root/Desktop`, save, log out and log in again.

Comment: Thanks. It has been solved. Although I tried that before but this time it worked ^.^